# Would redux mapDispatchToProps creates new functions everytime states is updated?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

> By using .bind or use Arrow functions in JSX props. A bind call or
>   arrow function in a JSX prop will create a brand new function on every
>   single render.

Does that mean that the following example would create `cardList.length` new functions of `() => props.pressCard(card)` every time the component re-render?

```
const cards = cardList.map(card =>
      <TouchableOpacity key={card.id} onPress={() => props.pressCard(card)}>
        <Card {...card} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
  );
```

If that is the case, how about the `mapDispatchToProps` of Redux? For example,

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    pressCard: (card) => dispatch(homeActions.pressCard(card))
});
```

Does it also create new functions when states in a component update?

Comment: The first one definetly creates new functions every render. The second one - I don't see a reason to run mapDispatchToProps on state change since you can't access state from there. Not sure how redux handles this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure that doing,

```
onPress={() => props.pressCard(card)
```

creates cardList.length new functions

The way to overcome this is to create a component using a class and bind the function once in the constructor,

Eg:

```
class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.handlePressCard = this.handlePressCard.bind(this)
  }
  handlePressCard(e) {
    const card = e.currentTarget.dataset.id
    // Find the card with the above `id`
    this.props.pressCard(card)
  }
  render () {
    return (
      cardList.map((card) => (
        <TouchableOpacity key={card.id} data-id={card.id} onPress={this.handlePressCard}>
          <Card {...card} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ))
    )
  }
}
```

Ques-2:

It depends more on implementation details. As far as I know it will be loaded only once if you are returning same object without any comparison with store.getState() and manipulating the object (I might be wrong also).

Comment: or just define it inline `handlePressCard = (e) => {` then you dont need to write out a bind for every function :)

Answer (score 2):

A `mapDispatchToProps` function returns whatever you've written it to return.  In your example, it will return a new `pressCard()` function as a prop when it runs.

However, **by default `connect` will only call your `mapDispatch` function once**, when your component instance is created.  It will *not* call it again when an action is dispatched.

If you declare your `mapDispatch` function as taking two parameters, it will be called with the wrapped component's props as the second argument, like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    pressCard: (card) => dispatch(homeActions.pressCard(card, ownProps.itemId))
});
```

In that case, it will get called again any time the incoming props change, but that's probably not going to be for "every dispatched action".

There's an "object shorthand" syntax for binding methods, which is simpler to use:

```
const actions = {
    pressCard : homeActions.pressCard
}

export default connect(mapState, actions)(MyComponent);
```